# How to make photo effects with php, skew images etc?

Tags: php, image-processing

How do I make image effects to rotate and skew images in PHP?

I want to know the underlying stuff the magic, what php extension should i look into and learn to make this happen, any good tutorials online to make cool image effects?

Comment: This is a very valid question to ask. I agree that you must try and google it first but we are all on the same side here. +1

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted either.  It seems like a valid question. +1

Comment: It was downvoted because it contained a link to a humor website -- which, for a user who just registered 2 days ago, is very suspicious spam-like behavior.

Answer (score 1):

For image effects and overlaying an image on top of another:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at ezcomponents

http://ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/ImageAnalysis 
http://ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/ImageConversion

Has some very strong image analysis and conversion methods.

Answer (score 1):

As [stillstanding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084784/how-to-make-photo-effects-with-php-skew-images-etc/4084846#4084846) says you can use both GD or imageMagick to work with images.

To distort an image I found:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-distortimage.php

To skewing an image with GD look at this post:
[How would I skew an image with GD Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650358/how-would-i-skew-an-image-with-gd-library)

Answer (score 1):

i have seen a post here which shows 13 php image effects, you can have a try to see whether it's something you need.

http://thetutlage.com/post=TUT160

http://www.thetutlage.com/demo/imageManipulation/example1.php