# 3D texturing with PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, texture-mapping

I want to generate this [http://de.novumpro.com/typo3temp/pics/0512014950.jpg http://de.novumpro.com/typo3temp/pics/0512014950.jpg](http://de.novumpro.com/typo3temp/pics/0512014950.jpg) with PHP and two source images: gray book background and book cover texture (front-facing, not rotated).

Combining two images would not be a problem with GD, but I need to 3D rotate the book cover first.

[Image_3D](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_3D/redirected) doesn't do texturing.

Will ImageMagic help me?

Any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you need to do is skew the image, like [How would I skew an image with GD Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650358/how-would-i-skew-an-image-with-gd-library)

Answer (score 0):

*Real* 3D is out of the question with ImageMagick, but faking it (i.e. skewing and rotating bitmaps so they fit) is possible. See e.g. this [IM Forum thread](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=11726).

See also the [distortion chapter](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/) in the IM examples book.