# Trying to skew an image with PHP's GD Library

Tags: php, image, gd, transform, skew

I've been looking everywhere to try and find a function to skew an image with php using the GD library. I've read threads where ImageMagick has been suggested but I unfortunately don't have access to that library on my server so I'm forced to use GD.
I'm looking for something where I can specify the source image and destination image and then 4 sets of X and Y coordinates for each corner of the image. So something like this would be ideal:

```
bool skewImage(resource $src_im, resource $dst_im, int $x1, int $y1, int $x2, int $y2, int $x3, int $y3, int $x4, int $y4)
```

If anyone has or knows of a function like this or similar that would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How would I skew an image with GD Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650358/how-would-i-skew-an-image-with-gd-library).  It also happens to be the #1 result in Google for `gd skew`.

Comment: I read that thread and the answers provided are not quite what I'm looking for. That function will only skew one side or the other, similar but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual is an amazing place. [This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-distortimage.php#103403) pretty much covers a lot of scenarios. Use the 'Perspective' section. Below example is slightly modified to use the width and height from the image.

```php
$image = new imagick( "grid.jpg" ); 
$points = array( 
              0,0, 80,120, # top left  
              $image->width,0, 300,10, # top right
              0,$image->height, 5,400, # bottom left 
              $image->width,$image->height, 380,390 # bottum right
            );

$image->setimagebackgroundcolor("#fad888");
$image->setImageVirtualPixelMethod( imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BACKGROUND );
$image->distortImage( Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $points, TRUE );

header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" ); 
echo $image;
```

Comment: This answer uses the imagick class, which is not the GD library